# Generate wrapper for the Jaxb generated ObjectFactory methods nillable=true, minOccurs=0

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am using JAXB, I have xsd files which I cannot modify which has elements with

```
minOccurs="0" nillable="true"
```

Which results that in the generated ObjectFactory class I have a lot of code like:

```
JAXBElement<SomeObject>
```

Then the code, that I  have to write to both marshall and unmarshall is boilerplate and ugly.

Is there a way to generate somehow automaticaly another layer of abstraction so that I would have some other ObjectFactory class as well, but it would not operate on JAXBElement but instead would have it wrapped in some methods? Like it is when in the binding.xjb you specify the following:

```
<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel" generateElementProperty="false">
```

which is unfortunately not an option for me.

Comment: Try the [Simplify Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin). It might work for this case as well - but no guarantees. If it doesn't, send me a [MCVE]. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will give it a try.